# I can not create a "researcher" using the sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I try to create a new researcher but I just go into catch, and I do not get any errors. I am new using sequelize, I need a lot of help for this problem, my complete code in git: https://github.com/chanudinho/RevYou-BackEnd.
I can't explain it better, please if you need to download the project and test it. Sorry for my english =x

researcherController.js

```
const Researcher = require('../../sequelize/models/researcher');
const createResearcher= async (req, res) => {
 try{
    Researcher.create({name: 'name', email: 'email', password: 'password'});
    return res.status(201).send('sucesso');
 }catch (err){
    return res.status(500).send('error');
 }
}
```

models/researcher.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Researcher = sequelize.define('Researcher', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
  password: DataTypes.STRING
});

return Researcher;
```

};

migrations/20190114200431-create-researcher

```
module.exports = {
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
return queryInterface.createTable('Researcher', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  email: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  password:{
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
 });
},
 down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  return queryInterface.dropTable('Researcher');
 }
};
```

models/index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('../../config/database.js');

const db = {};
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);

fs
 .readdirSync(__dirname)
 .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== path.basename(__filename)) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
 .forEach((file) => {
 const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
 db[model.name] = model;
 });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
 if (db[modelName].associate) {
 db[modelName].associate(db);
 }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing the model file and this is not right, your `index.js` within model maps all model files by adding the sequelize instance and the datatypes. You should always import the `index`.

If you import the model `index` and give a `console.log()` in it will see that you have the object of your model and the instance of the sequelize.

```
const db = require('../../sequelize/models/index');
console.log(db)
```

Inside the exit will have something like this: Example:

```
Researcher: Researcher,
sequelize: 
  Sequelize { ....
```

To access your model you can do the following. By using [destructuring assignment](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring), you extract the model from within the index.

> Result

```
const { Researcher } = require('../../sequelize/models/index')
const createResearcher= async (req, res) => {
    try{
            await Researcher.create({name: 'name', email: 'email', password: 'password'});
            return res.status(201).send('sucesso')
    }catch (err){
            return res.status(500).send('error');
    }
}
```

Whenever you create a new file inside the model folder, it will be mapped by `index.js` and added inside the matrix and using destructuring you can access or use the matrix key itself.

```
const db = require('../../sequelize/models/index')
const createResearcher= async (req, res) => {
    try{
            await db.Researcher.create({name: 'name', email: 'email', password: 'password'});
            return res.status(201).send('sucesso')
    }catch (err){
            return res.status(500).send('error');
    }
}
```